# contact geometry good reference

Tags: projective-geometry, symplectic-geometry, contact-topology

I am working on which seems to be a classical result : the isomorphism between the cotangent bundle of projective space (with zero section removed) and the cotangent bundle of its dual projective space. I proved with non-constructive argument that there is symplecto-morphism

I am looking for a good reference when I can find this subject detailed and more specifically the generating function that gives rise to the symplecto-morphism.